# Full Screen Dialog, programmatically setting text

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a fullscreen dialog (defined in `FullScreenDialog()`) being shown on click of a button, but would like to be able to also programmatically set elements of the dialog. Something like this in the host fragment's `onCreateView()`:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    view.btn_computePaletteFragment.setOnClickListener {

        val fragmentManager = fragmentManager
        val fullScreenDialog = FullScreenDialog()
        val transaction = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
        transaction?.add(android.R.id.content, fullScreenDialog)?.addToBackStack(null)?.commit()

        fullScreenDialog.dialog_title.text = "Computed Palette Input"

    }

    return view
}
```

and the corresponding class for the custom fullscreen dialog Fragment:

```
class FullScreenDialog : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(org.plainsound.hejicalc.R.layout.fs_dialog, container, false)
        view.button_close.setOnClickListener { dismiss() }
        return view
    }

}
```

However, I get a Null pointer exception: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Code you have put that is button click, code for onCreateView() Please.

Comment: Remove "org.plainsound.hejicalc" before R.layout.fs_dialog if layout is inside layout folder.

Comment: Strangely, this is what I had initially, but `R.layout.fs_dialog` alone returned an unresolved reference. Found `import android.R` in the imports, removing it just now fixed that. But nevertheless, when I click `btn_computePaletteFragment` I still get the Null pointer exception. As if it hasn't been created yet, though it has already been instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an exception is because the dialog hasn't been inflated yet. I know you mentioned in a comment that it's already been instantiated, but this just means that the object has been constructed, it provides no guarantee that the Android system has called `onCreateView` for the dialog yet.

However even if you were to get this to work, through a delay or layout listener it would be incredibly bad practice because of how Android manages fragments. If there is a rotation, low memory issue or something similar, the system can recreate the fragments just using the default constructor which will result in you losing the state you set.

In order to to this properly you should pass arguments to the fragment using `setArguments` and then retrieving them in the dialog with `getArguments`. These arguments are managed by the system and will be kept regardless of whether the fragment is recreated.

You can also use a [shared `ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) if you have complex data to share, or the new fragment results API which you can read about [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate).

Comment: So I guess this is handled by an Interface using the Main Activity as a middle man between the two fragments. I've got it working to a certain extent, but am encountering a new problem with the close button of the receiving interface. Will post a new question to be clear.

Comment: Well out of the three solutions I recommended, a shared `ViewModel` might be the best bet.

Comment: I am completely unfamiliar with it, but am reading the documentation now. Is it the least fussy? I didn't realise sending information between Fragments would be so complicated, but the reasons behind it make sense...

Comment: Least fussy is exactly how I would describe it. No casting or key-value pairs needed! But yes, communicating between components in Android is a nightmare